# A standard button in a jquery Dialog acts like the submit button of the Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I got a problem with a button behaviour:

it's a  inside a jQuery Tab, inside a jQuery Dialog, inside a .

When the button is clicked, instead of executing a function,  its validate the form wich refresh the page and insert a new blank entry in my database.

I just want it to append a new  in the one i tell it.

the html:

```
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<button id="newgroup-anacuad">Añadir una fecha de fotos</button><br />
<div id="newgroup-divfotos"></div>
</td>
```

the javascript:

```
$('#diagnewgroup').dialog({
...
open:function(){
    $("#newgroup-anacuad").button();
    $("#newgroup-anacuad").bind("onclick",function(){
        var txt='blabla';
        $("#newgroup-divfotos").append(txt);
    });
...
}
buttons:
{
'Validar':function()
{
    var valid=true;
    var errores='';
        if(valid==true)
        {
        $('#formnewgroup').submit();
    }
    else
    {
        alert(errores);
        }
},
'Cancelar':function()
{
    $(this).dialog('close');
    $('#diagnewgroup').remove();
}
}});
```

Does anyone has encountered this before?

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
   <button id="newgroup-anacuad">Añadir una fecha de fotos</button>
```

with

```
   <input type="button" id="newgroup-anacuad" value="Añadir una fecha de fotos"/>
```

In some browsers

```
   <button>
```

is usually acts as

```
   <input type="submit">
```

Additionally you should replace **"onclick"** with **"click"** in

```
   $("#newgroup-anacuad").bind("onclick",function(){
       var txt='blabla';
       $("#newgroup-divfotos").append(txt);
   });
```

or you can rewrite in to something like:

```
   $("#newgroup-anacuad").click(function(){
       var txt='blabla';
       $("#newgroup-divfotos").append(txt);
   });
```

Comment: you got any facts which browsers convert does this?

Comment: yep, here http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5 default 'type' value for button tag is 'submit'

Comment: Well it's effectively solve the submit problem but the function still not running

Comment: ah, yes. You also should replace bind("onclick",...) with bind("click",...). In jQuery you should skip 'on' prefix. Or you can replace .bind('click', function) with .click(function) as I wrote in updated answer

Comment: Hum... It's Friday +1  for the "click", problem solved, let's get a Gin Tonic!!!
Thanks VilPy